# using C and cuda create shared library got error at link stage

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I was really struggled with this error when I try to build a shared library. My code utilize the Lapacke library and also CUDA. when I compile them, there are no errors(I compile them as)

```
gcc -m64 -Wall -fPIC -c xxx.c -o xxx.o $(INC)
```

where INC includes all directories

```
INC=-I. -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux/ I$/home/sniu/lapack-3.5.0/lapacke/include/ -I${CUDA_INSTALL_PATH}/include/ -I/home/sniu/CBLAS/include/
```

for cuda part, I wrote it as:

```
nvcc -m64 -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler -fPIC $(INC) -c xxx.cu -o xxx.o
```

but I got the error message at the link stage:

> gcc -m64 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -fPIC  -g -shared  -o libjniWrapper.so jniWrapper.o cholesky_inv.o wls_acc.o utils.o -L/home/sniu/lapack-3.5.0 -L/opt/cuda-toolkit/5.5.22/lib64 -lm -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lrt -lcudart -lcublas -ldl
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /home/sniu/lapack-3.5.0/liblapacke.a(lapacke_dpotrf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /home/sniu/lapack-3.5.0/liblapacke.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am very sure libraries are there, I really confused why I got this error. 
Any suggestions are appreciated, Thank you so much!

Comment: The library causing problems also needs to be compiled with `-fPIC`

Comment: Your lapacke library hasn't been built correctly. You need to fix that by recompiling it with the correct options (and learn to read the error messages, the linker is telling you *exactly* what is wrong and what to do). I'm removing the CUDA tag, this has nothing to do with CUDA.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks a lot for your reply, I test lapacke lib api installed on my computer, it works fine. Do you mean I need to recompile the lapacke library add option with -fPIC? Thank you for your patience